# Google Drive App - Method makeCopy (string, string) not found

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script I get an error `"Method makeCopy(string,string) not found"` when the below function is invoked. However I cannot see my mistake. The auto-completition feature of the Google Apps Script even offers the method.

```
function createDuplicateDocument(sourceId, name) {
    var source = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceId);
    var newFile = source.makeCopy(name, TARGET_FOLDER);

    return DriveApp.getFileById(newFile.getId());
}
```

(The variable `TARGET_FOLDER`is a global var.)

Does anyone of you have an idea?

Comment: showing the target folder assignment would be of more help than just stating that it is a global variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the method is `makeCopy(string, Folder)` so the error you are seeing suggests the `TARGET_FOLDER` global variable you are passing is a `String` and not a `Folder` object.

You don't give details of what String you are passing in `TARGET_FOLDER` but if it were a UID, for example, then you would pass it as `source.makeCopy(name, DriveApp.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER))` for instance.

Comment: Yes, my var `TARGET_FOLDER` contains an UID. Your solution is what I needed to do. Seems so logical now.. Thanks.